# Launch New Bash Shell And Run Commands

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew, iterm

I am attempting to launch a new shell and run a command in the new shell, and then leave the shell running interactively. I attempted the process [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/how-to-invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-the-new-shell-and-then-give-control-bac) [ `(bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; some_command')` ]. The reason for this is that bash 5.x on Macos 13 (safely installed at /usr/local/bin/bash via Homebrew ) does not execute ~/.bashrc properly, but running source ~/.bashrc works when manually executed.

I have oh-my-bash installed.

```
➜  ~ cat .bash_profile

# Created by `pipx` on 2023-05-08 20:21:52
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/jpg/.local/bin"

test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash" || true

➜  ~ cat .bashrc
# Enable the subsequent settings only in interactive sessions
case $- in
  *i*) ;;
    *) return;;
esac

# Path to your oh-my-bash installation.
export OSH='/Users/jpg/.oh-my-bash'

# Set name of the theme to load. Optionally, if you set this to "random"
# it'll load a random theme each time that oh-my-bash is loaded.
OSH_THEME="font"

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# OMB_CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion. Case
# sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# OMB_HYPHEN_SENSITIVE="false"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_OSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you don't want the repository to be considered dirty
# if there are untracked files.
# SCM_GIT_DISABLE_UNTRACKED_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to completely ignore the presence
# of untracked files in the repository.
# SCM_GIT_IGNORE_UNTRACKED="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.  One of the following values can
# be used to specify the timestamp format.
# * 'mm/dd/yyyy'     # mm/dd/yyyy + time
# * 'dd.mm.yyyy'     # dd.mm.yyyy + time
# * 'yyyy-mm-dd'     # yyyy-mm-dd + time
# * '[mm/dd/yyyy]'   # [mm/dd/yyyy] + [time] with colors
# * '[dd.mm.yyyy]'   # [dd.mm.yyyy] + [time] with colors
# * '[yyyy-mm-dd]'   # [yyyy-mm-dd] + [time] with colors
# If not set, the default value is 'yyyy-mm-dd'.
# HIST_STAMPS='yyyy-mm-dd'

# Uncomment the following line if you do not want OMB to overwrite the existing
# aliases by the default OMB aliases defined in lib/*.sh
# OMB_DEFAULT_ALIASES="check"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $OSH/custom?
# OSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# To disable the uses of "sudo" by oh-my-bash, please set "false" to
# this variable.  The default behavior for the empty value is "true".
OMB_USE_SUDO=true

# To enable/disable display of Python virtualenv and condaenv
# OMB_PROMPT_SHOW_PYTHON_VENV=true  # enable
# OMB_PROMPT_SHOW_PYTHON_VENV=false # disable

# Which completions would you like to load? (completions can be found in ~/.oh-my-bash/completions/*)
# Custom completions may be added to ~/.oh-my-bash/custom/completions/
# Example format: completions=(ssh git bundler gem pip pip3)
# Add wisely, as too many completions slow down shell startup.
completions=(
  git
  composer
  ssh
)

# Which aliases would you like to load? (aliases can be found in ~/.oh-my-bash/aliases/*)
# Custom aliases may be added to ~/.oh-my-bash/custom/aliases/
# Example format: aliases=(vagrant composer git-avh)
# Add wisely, as too many aliases slow down shell startup.
aliases=(
  general
)

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-bash/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-bash/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
  git
  bashmarks
)

# Which plugins would you like to conditionally load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-bash/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-bash/custom/plugins/
# Example format:
#  if [ "$DISPLAY" ] || [ "$SSH" ]; then
#      plugins+=(tmux-autoattach)
#  fi

source "$OSH"/oh-my-bash.sh

# User configuration
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/rsa_id"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-bash libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-bash
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the OSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias bashconfig="mate ~/.bashrc"
# alias ohmybash="mate ~/.oh-my-bash"
alias lla="ls -la"
alias lar="ls -laR"
alias move="mv"
alias ll="ls -l"
alias cls="clear"
alias md="mkdir"
alias copy="cp"
#alias rm="rmdir $*"
#alias rmr="rmdir /s $*"
alias cd..="cd .."
alias cd...="cd ../.."
alias cd....="cd ../../.."
alias lsusb="ioreg -p IOUSB -w0 | sed 's/[^o]*o //; s/@.*$//' | grep -v '^Root.*'"
alias ftp="ncftp"
tabs -4

# Created by `pipx` on 2023-05-08 20:21:52
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/jpg/.local/bin"
```

Comment: What do you mean with `does not execute ~/.bashrc properly`? This might be easier to fix than trying some magic.

Comment: Having said that: I have `test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc` in `.profile`, this works fine.

Comment: As @nohillside eluded to, I don't understand what you're doing here:  `(bash -rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; some_command'`  What are you trying to accomplish with this?  Bash, by default reads `~/.bashrc`   I see no reason to specifcy what it already sources.

Comment: `Bash` reads `~/.bashrc` for non-login, interactive shells.  As documented.  If you are expecting a login shell to read `~/.bashrc`, you should use the workaround from @nohillside or a similar one from `~/.bash_profile`.